# Why does this Thread freeze the UI

Tags: android, multithreading

In my code I have to send a message as long as my `ToggleButton` is checked. To prevent the UI Thread from freezing, I put the action in a seperate Thread.

My Problem is, that it still freezes, but I don't know why

This is the relevant code:

```
private ToggleButton.OnClickListener lightMirrorOnClickListener = new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (lightMirrorBtn.isChecked()) {
            lightThread = new LightThread();
            lightThread.start();
        } else if(!lightMirrorBtn.isChecked()) {
            lightThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

};

class LightThread extends Thread {

    Handler lightHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable light = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            while (lightMirrorBtn.isChecked()) {
                lightTxMsg.frameFormat = ConstantList.STANDARD_FRAME;
                lightTxMsg.frameType = ConstantList.DATA_FRAME;
                lightTxMsg.dataLength = (byte) 8;
                lightTxMsg.messageID = 0x3C1;
                int[] messageArray = AMBI_LIGHT;
                for (int i = 0; i < lightTxMsg.dataLength; i++) {
                    lightTxMsg.data[i] = messageArray[i];
                }

                returnCode = demoController.transmitMessage(lightTxMsg,
                        ConstantList.BINARY_FORMAT);    
            }
        }
    };

    public void run() {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
                lightHandler.post(light);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
This was the solution for the problem:

```
private ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener lightMirrorOnClickListener = new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked == true) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lightTxMsg.frameFormat = ConstantList.STANDARD_FRAME;
                    lightTxMsg.frameType = ConstantList.DATA_FRAME;
                    lightTxMsg.dataLength = (byte) 8;
                    lightTxMsg.messageID = 0x3C1;
                    int[] messageArray = AMBI_LIGHT_ON;
                    for (int i = 0; i < lightTxMsg.dataLength; i++) {
                        lightTxMsg.data[i] = messageArray[i];
                    }

                    returnCode = demoController.transmitMessage(lightTxMsg,
                            ConstantList.BINARY_FORMAT);
                }
            }).start();

        }  else if (!isChecked) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lightTxMsg.frameFormat = ConstantList.STANDARD_FRAME;
                    lightTxMsg.frameType = ConstantList.DATA_FRAME;
                    lightTxMsg.dataLength = (byte) 8;
                    lightTxMsg.messageID = 0x3C1;
                    int[] messageArray = AMBI_LIGHT_OFF;
                    for (int i = 0; i < lightTxMsg.dataLength; i++) {
                        lightTxMsg.data[i] = messageArray[i];
                    }

                    returnCode = demoController.transmitMessage(lightTxMsg,
                            ConstantList.BINARY_FORMAT);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I suggest you check some tutorial about multi-threading in Java, you have several mistakes in there. For example extend Thread and create a Runnable inside it is redundant, a thread is already a Runnable.

Comment: could you maybe name some of them, so its easier to do research ?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a place to learn but to ask specific questions. You shouldn't even attempt to write multi-threading code without reading how first. I can point to [Oracle's offical tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), they're a good place to start.

Comment: Btw when it does freeze? When it's checked or not?

Comment: Is freezes when its checked

Comment: your `transmitMessage` might be doing some blocking operation on UI thread. Or maybe the array you're iterating over is too large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Handler lightHandler = new Handler();
```

When you create your handler your thread has not yet started. It is just being created. So, according to the `Handler`'s [default constructor documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28%29) this handler is associated "with the Looper for the current thread" ... which is currently the main(UI) thread. So you post your messages on the main thread.

You don't need a `Handler` to post your runnable on. You can either:

1. Create a Thread and specify it's actions in the `run()` method
   or
2. Pass a `Runnable` to your thread that will be executed in your thread using the [`Thread(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) constructor

Here are the basic articles about `Threads`:

1. [Processes and threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)
2. [Keeping your app responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)
3. [Specifying the Code to Run on a Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html)

Comment: Good information, thx! But I'm wondering, why this only is a problem on this Thread. On all my other Threads I create a new Handler object at the same position

Comment: I don't know what are your other Threads doing. This one has a loop that runs while while lightMirrorBtn.isChecked(). And it is also sleeping for 60ms. Do you have those long-running actions in the other threads? Are you sure that they (and their handler) are also created in the UI thread (in onClick, for example)?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. A `Handler` can only be instantiated in UIThread (main thread), or a thread that has called `Looper.prepare()`, which AFAIK you can't call manually. And no, `Handler#post` (and family) does not run in the UIThread.

Comment: They all do long-running tasks. And most of them are created in the onCreate()

Comment: Sorry, you're right, as the documentation says about `Handler#post`: *"The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached"*.

Comment: So my Handler runs on Thread as its a class variable of lightThread. So it should not block the UI Thread in my thoughts

Comment: @Fraggles - try to follow the guides and simply create a new Thread class that has its actions inside its run() method. Then simply start the thread. Don't make the things complicated with Handlers.

Comment: @Fraggles - no. Your Handler runs on the UI thread. It might be a class member of your Thread subclass but the Thread object is created on the UI thread. So the Handler is also created in the UI thread and associated with it. This happens before your thread is started.

Comment: thx for your help, it now works without handler and extra Thread class. I'll mark your answer as correct, cause it leaded to my solution :)